# Action one link and redirect to another using php or javascript

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, buddypress

I’ve been battling with this for hours, I wonder if anyone can help.

I want to make a redirect script which first actions a link. I have a link generated by php which deletes the current user’s avatar. This link works (user avatar is deleted) however the link itself doesn’t lead anywhere, it just reloads whichever page it is launched from (I haven’t quite worked out how yet, I presume this is a feature of wordpress/buddypress which I am using). My aim is that on arrival to a particular page (page1.php), the delete avatar link is automatically actioned, and then the user is redirected to another page. So:

1)  User arrives at page1.php

2)  Script fires this link :

```
    <a href="<?php if ( bp_get_user_has_avatar() ) : print 'mysite.net/members/'; echo userpro_profile_data('user_login', $user_id2); print '/'; bp_avatar_delete_link(); else : 'something-else.php'; endif; ?>"></a
```

3)  User redirected to page2.php

I guess there may be some way to do this in javascript/ajax but I hardly use it so not really sure how. I’m struggling to get it to work in php also. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: missing echo : `else : echo 'something-else.php';`

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the page via Javascript using [Location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = <?= $new_location ?>;
</script>
```

Or you can do it in PHP after performing required operations using code like this:

```
header("Location: {$new_location}");
```

But notice that if you redirecting via [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) you should not echo enything to the page before it.

Or you can use [wp_redirect()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) if youre doing it in Wordpress.

Comment: Should be using [`wp_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) - trying to set the header directly will likely conflict with the general workings of Wordpress.

Comment: @Emissary and by using wp_redirect(), you're right, thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks. Any thought on how to action the other link first?